# Problem when trying to install NanoTCAD

Tags: software-installation, python, 22.04, python3

I tried to install NanoTCAD to use for my scientific research. the program page linked below:
http://vides.nanotcad.com/vides/documentation/installation-4

However, the Ubuntu showed error screen like this:

```
laptop@LAPTOP-EHGAEMR1:~$ cd pyViDES
laptop@LAPTOP-EHGAEMR1:~/pyViDES$ sudo ./install.sh
[sudo] password for laptop:
sudo: unable to execute ./install.sh: No such file or directory
laptop@LAPTOP-EHGAEMR1:~/pyViDES$ sudo bash install.sh
Compiling NANOTCAD ViDES module for python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configure.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
gcc -fPIC -O3 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/numpy/core/include/numpy -c NanoTCAD_ViDESmod.c
NanoTCAD_ViDESmod.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "Python.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:48: NanoTCAD_ViDESmod.o] Error 1
gcc -fPIC -O3 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/numpy/core/include/numpy -c NanoTCAD_ViDESmod.c
NanoTCAD_ViDESmod.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "Python.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:48: NanoTCAD_ViDESmod.o] Error 1
laptop@LAPTOP-EHGAEMR1:~/pyViDES$
```

I tried to search for solution on internet to no avail. Can anyone please enlighten me how to get through this problem?

I currently using Ubuntu22.04 and Python3.10 BTW.